# How do you check for consecutive integers as strings in python?

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm making a function **is_consecutive** that returns True if a string of integers separated by a hyphen (-) are consecutive and False otherwise.

For example, if **is_consecutive("10-9-8-7-6")** and **is_consecutive("1-2-3-4-5")** is **True** but **is_consecutive("1-2-3-5-4")** returns **False**.

I don't know how to approach the problem. So far I tried splicing the strings and trying to check if the string was a number, parse it, then check for consecutivity to no avail.

I have tried doing this

```
def is_consecutive(x):
    ls = list(x)
    for i in ls:
        if i in ls == "-":

    print(ls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
def is_consecutive(x):
    ls = list(map(int, x.split('-')))
    diffs = set(x-y for x, y in zip(ls, ls[1:]))
    return len(diffs) == 1 and diffs.pop() in (1, -1)

>>> is_consecutive("1-2-3-4-5-6")
True
>>> is_consecutive("1-2-3-4-6-5")
False
>>> is_consecutive("3-2-1")
True
```

The first line turns your string into a list of integers:
1. [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on hyphens
2. cast to int using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

The second line collects all differences of neighbors.
1. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the list with itself offset by 1 to get an iterable of pairs of neighbours
2. calculate the difference for each such pair
3. turn it into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) (keeps only distinct vaules)

The third line checks that there is only one such difference and that it is either `1` or `-1`.
1. check set cardinality, using [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)
2. check that the one element by [`pop`ing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.pop) it

Comment: thank you so much!!! can you explain to me the code that you used on the second line? that's the first time i have seen that

Comment: Added some more explanation and links

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to compare the input list to one generated from a `range` object starting from the first item and ending in the last item of the list, taking into account of the direction of the sequence based on whether the last item is greater or lower than the first item:

```
def is_consecutive(x):
    lst = list(map(int, x.split('-')))
    direction = lst[-1] > lst[0] or -1
    return lst == list(range(lst[0], lst[-1] + direction, direction))
```